# How to permanently change "useRecommendedPerformanceSettings" in firefox browser using python even after relaunching the browser?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

In this code, settings are changing. But if I relaunch the Firefox browser again, it is reverting back to the old settings

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
driver = Firefox()

driver.get('about:preferences')
element=driver.find_element("id", "useRecommendedPerformanceSettings") # search for the "Performance" section and click on it
if element.get_attribute("checked") == "true":
    element.click()
    print("Changed settings successfully")
```

I want to change the Recommended settings in Firefox. Using the above code, it is changing 1 time. If I relaunch the browser, the settings are not saved. How to change the useRecommendedPerformanceSettings permanently?
Need to uncheck the recommended settings box.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a profile and start your firefox driver with the said profile

1. Create a new Firefox profile, go to about:profiles in firefox and add a new profile
   [image]
2. Copy the root directory path for new profile
3. After that click on launch profile in new browser
4. Now in the new tab that opens go to "about:preferences" and uncheck highperformance settings and close it

Now use below code to start your firefox driver with new profile

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('add root directory profile path here')

# Create a Firefox driver instance with the updated preferences
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), firefox_profile=fp)
```

Now when the browser launces it will load the profile with Highperformance settings disabled